# convert curl to requests using multipart/mixed in python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to convert the following curl post to a Python request:

```
curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" -X POST --form 
'session.id=e7a29776-5783-49d7-afa0-b0e688096b5e' --form 'ajax=upload' 
--form 'file=@myproject.zip;type=application/zip' --form 'project=MyProject;type/plain' https://localhost:8443/manager
```

I used [curl.trillworks.com](http://curl.trillworks.com) to make an auto conversion but it didn't work. I also tried the following:

```
sessionID = e7a29776-5783-49d7-afa0-b0e688096b5e
project = 'file.zip'
metadata = json.dumps({"documentType":"multipart/mixed"})
files = {
         'meta' : ('', metadata , 'application/zip'),
         'data':(project, 'multipart/mixed', 'application/octet-stream')}
data = {'ajax':'upload','project':'test','session.id':sessionId}
cookie = {'azkaban.browser.session.id':sessionId}
response=requests.post('https://'+azkabanURL+'/manager',
data=data,verify=False,files=files)
print response.text
```

I got the following error:

```
<p>Problem accessing /manager. Reason:
<pre>    INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NullPointerException
    at azkaban.webapp.servlet.ProjectManagerServlet.ajaxHandleUpload(ProjectManagerServlet.java:1664)
    at azkaban.webapp.servlet.ProjectManagerServlet.handleMultiformPost(ProjectManagerServlet.java:183)
    at azkaban.webapp.servlet.LoginAbstractAzkabanServlet.doPost(LoginAbstractAzkabanServlet.java:276)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector$SslConnection.run(SslSocketConnector.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Can't figure out what I'm missing here??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer after trying out some of the examples from [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) site and finally it worked.

```
data = {'ajax':'upload','project':'test','session.id':sessionId}
files  = {'file':('projects.zip',open('projects.zip','rb'),'application/zip')}
response=requests.post('https://'+azkabanURL+'/manager',data=data,verify=False,files=files)
print response.text
print response.status_code
```

Answer (score 1):

For the future reference I recommend you to check this online tool:
http://curl.trillworks.com/
it converts curl to python requests, node and php.
It has helped my multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your post but I already mentioned in my question that I used curl.trilworks but the conversion I got from them didn't work.

Comment: it usually works well, but it's true - not always 1:1